# Where to run the flume agent that writes to HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I have 25-20 agents sending the data to couple of **collector agents** and and these collector agents then have to write it to the HDFS.

Where to run these collector agents? On the Data node of the Hadoop cluster or outside of the cluster? What are the pros/cons of each and how are people currently running them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tier 2 flume agents use hdfsSink write directly to HDFS. what's more , Tier1 can use failover sinkgroup. In case of one of tier 2 flume agent is down.

Comment: Question is, if I should run tier 2 agents on data nodes?

Comment: no need.if you run tier2 in datanodes and use  filechannel,disk IO lead datanode worst performing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how running on data node lead to worst performance?

Comment: for recovery from failure,we use filechannel in production environment.filechannel  store every event in disk,hdfsSink take event from disk.if you run flume in datanode,flume and datenode will contest with disk IO.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your using something like Flume.  If that's the case, the Flume agent (at least the first tier) runs where ever the data is being sourced from.  IE: Web Server for Web Logs..

Flume does support other protocols, like JMS, so the location will vary in those scenario's.

For production clusters, you don't want to run "agents" like flume on Datanodes.  Best to level the resources of that hardware for the cluster.

If you have a lot of agents, you'll want to use a tiered architecture to consolidate and funnel the numerous sources into a smaller set of agents that will write to HDFS.  This helps control visibility and exposure of the cluster to external servers.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear as I wanted. I am using tiered architecture of flume. My question was where does the last tier that writes to HDFS live for best write throughput? Tier 1 agents run on app server VMs, tier 2 flume agents run on dedicated boxes, and where should we run the tier 3 flume agents?